The video file doesn't load in android studio for flutter project
I'm trying to insert a video file into an app interface. I've been testing to insert a whale video 5 seconds long, but the screen turns blank, while all the other elements load. I can't find the reason for this, since the file location and pubspec.yaml location specified seem correct
this is my main.dart code file:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: VideoListScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<VideoData> videos = [
    VideoData('Grade 1 Chapter 7 ', 'assets/whale.mp4'),

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Video List'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: videos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final video = videos[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(video.title),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => VideoPlayerScreen(video: video),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoData video;

  VideoPlayerScreen({required this.video});

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.video.path);
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.video.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                ),
                VideoProgressIndicator(_controller, allowScrubbing: true),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _controller.value.isPlaying ? _controller.pause() : _controller.play();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VideoData {
  final String title;
  final String path;

  VideoData(this.title, this.path);
}

this is mypubspec.yaml:
name: project_ip
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using flutter pub publish. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.3 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running flutter pub upgrade --major-versions. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run flutter pub outdated.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter




  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  video_player: ^2.4.10

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the analysis_options.yaml file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/whale.mp4


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages

this is the file location: E:\project_ip\assets\whale.mp4
mine is an old acer nitro i7, idk if the problems lies in the processor, I've got around 20gm space left in the c drive where the flutter is stored, the project is stored in E drive which has a much larger space left, or if this is a problem regarding my android studio setup.
